# Calculate the number of lines in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using the DataGridView and set:

```
AutoSizeRowsMode = DisplayedCell
```

&

```
RowDefaultCellStyle: WrapText=True
```

result:

[image]

How can I get an order with the number of line DataGridView. For example, in picture. Line= 8.

in picture:

```
Row1 = 2 Line & Row2 = 1 Line & Row3 = 4 Line & Row4 = 1 Line. -----> Line = 8
```

Comment: Why you need to find line count?

Comment: I don't get it? What you need? Array with rows in right order?

Comment: Excuse me. in picture 1.

Comment: I'm using the text in the DataGridView in reporting. I need to know are a few lines before sending this information to report consuming

Comment: I'm getting confused by this statement: "how can I get an order". Does that mean you want to order the rows by the number of lines? Or do you just want to know how many lines of text are in each row?

Comment: i just want to know how many lines of text are in each row.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use [`MeasureString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring.aspx) based on the current font and cell width. Here is the code that does what you want:

```
private int CountLines(DataGridView dataGridView)
{
    int totalLineCount = 0;
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle))
    {
        SizeF baselineSize = graphics.MeasureString("test line", dataGridView.Font);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
        {
            int cellLineCount = 0;

            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.Value == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                string value = cell.Value.ToString();
                SizeF size = graphics.MeasureString(value, dataGridView.Font, cell.Size.Width);
                int lines = (int)Math.Round(size.Height / baselineSize.Height);
                cellLineCount = Math.Max(cellLineCount, lines);
            }

            totalLineCount += cellLineCount;
        }
    }

    return totalLineCount;
}
```